# Can I included the missingingless Data in R

Tags: r, missing-data, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I am currently conducting a survival analysis on the first 312 rows of a data set posted at:

[Removing Missing Data Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66861419/removing-missing-data-values/66862329?noredirect=1#comment118209914_66862329)

I check for missing data and this is what **R** returns:

```
> apply(surv.df, 2, function(x) length(which(is.na(x))))
 V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  28   0   2   0   0  30   4   0   0
```

When I conduct a Cox-regression analysis I obtain the following:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Time, Status == 1) ~ log(V5) + V10 + log(V11) + 
    log(V13) + V14 + V16 + log(V19) + V20, data = surv.df)

  n= 310, number of events= 124 
   (2 observations deleted due to missingness)

               coef  exp(coef)   se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
log(V5)   1.6977282  5.4615258  0.4920161  3.451 0.000559 ***
V10       0.8223583  2.2758606  0.3032572  2.712 0.006693 ** 
log(V11)  0.7103807  2.0347658  0.1204626  5.897  3.7e-09 ***
log(V13) -2.3728128  0.0932182  0.7746120 -3.063 0.002190 ** 
V14       0.0018932  1.0018950  0.0009783  1.935 0.052967 .  
V16       0.0030053  1.0030098  0.0017212  1.746 0.080804 .  
log(V19)  2.8071931 16.5633615  1.1514466  2.438 0.014770 *  
V20       0.2898083  1.3361713  0.1392896  2.081 0.037469 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

         exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
log(V5)    5.46153    0.18310   2.08214   14.3258
V10        2.27586    0.43939   1.25607    4.1236
log(V11)   2.03477    0.49146   1.60685    2.5766
log(V13)   0.09322   10.72752   0.02042    0.4255
V14        1.00189    0.99811   0.99998    1.0038
V16        1.00301    0.99700   0.99963    1.0064
log(V19)  16.56336    0.06037   1.73395  158.2201
V20        1.33617    0.74841   1.01695    1.7556

Concordance= 0.859  (se = 0.017 )
Likelihood ratio test= 211.3  on 8 df,   p=<2e-16
Wald test            = 205.9  on 8 df,   p=<2e-16
Score (logrank) test = 281.9  on 8 df,   p=<2e-16
```

Is there a way to keep the 2 missing rows in the data set?

This leads to another problem: I am trying to plot the Martingale residuals, but I am unable to since there are 310 residuals and the `V11` variable *bilirubin* has 312 observations and so a plot is not possible.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably talking about this massage you got:

> (2 observations deleted due to missingness)

As you can see from your table:

```
apply(surv.df, 2, function(x) length(which(is.na(x))))
 V2  V3  V4  V5  V6  V7  V8  V9 V10 V11 V12 V13 V14 V15 V16 V17 V18 V19 V20 
  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  28   0   2   0   0  30   4   0   0
```

There are 30 missing values in V17 and 28 missing values in V12 but since neither V17 or V12 is not a regressor in your model / part of you formula there is no problem for these.

> Call:
> coxph(formula = Surv(Time, Status == 1) ~ log(V5) + V10 + log(V11) +
> log(V13) + V14 + V16 + log(V19) + V20, data = surv.df)

V14, which is part of your call/formula has 2 missing values - that is why there is a warning.

It isn't necessarily too bad, that these two observations got deleted for you model. If you don't want this, you could remove V14 from your formula. Or you could perform some imputation to replace these missing values with reasonable values. (maybe the mice package can help here).