# Predicting Survival using a coxph() object

Tags: r, prediction, survival-analysis, cox-regression

This is a continuation of the data set posted at:

[Removing Missing Data Values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66861419/removing-missing-data-values/66862329?noredirect=1#comment118209914_66862329)

I am trying to predict survival for the data below, where the first column is the index column and the columns are labelled V1 - V20:

```
313 4062 0 . 21915 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 3.65   .      .     .     . 378 11.0 .
314 3561 2 . 23741 1 . . . 0.5  1.4    . 3.04   .      .     .     . 331 12.1 4
315 2844 0 . 19724 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 4.03   .      .     .     . 226  9.8 4
316 2071 2 . 27394 1 . . . 0.5  0.7    . 3.96   .      .     .     .   . 11.3 4
317 3030 0 . 22646 1 . . . 0.0  0.8    . 2.48   .      .     .     . 273 10.0 .
318 1680 0 . 15706 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 3.68   .      .     .     . 306  9.5 2
319   41 2 . 16802 1 . . . 0.0  5.0    . 2.93   .      .     .     . 260 10.4 .
320 2403 0 . 16071 1 . . . 0.5  0.4    . 3.81   .      .     .     . 226 10.5 3
321 1170 0 . 22280 0 . . . 0.5  1.3    . 3.41   .      .     .     . 259 10.9 4
322 2011 2 . 23376 1 . . . 0.0  1.1    . 3.69   .      .     .     . 139 10.5 .
323 3523 0 . 14610 1 . . . 0.0  0.6    . 4.04   .      .     .     . 130 11.2 2
324 3468 0 . 23011 1 . . . 0.0  0.6    . 3.94   .      .     .     . 234 11.5 2
325 4795 0 . 12419 1 . . . 0.0  1.8    . 3.24   .      .     .     .   . 18.0 2
326 1236 0 . 18993 1 . . . 0.0  1.5    . 3.42   .      .     .     . 246 10.3 3
327 4214 0 . 17897 1 . . . 0.0  1.2    . 3.99   .      .     .     .   . 11.2 2
328 2111 2 . 19724 1 . . . 0.0  1.0    . 3.60   .      .     .     .   . 12.1 2
329 1462 2 . 23011 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 3.40   .      .     .     . 371 10.1 4
330 1746 2 . 19724 0 . . . 0.0  3.5    . 3.63   .      .     .     . 325 10.3 2
331   94 2 . 16802 1 . . . 0.5  3.1    . 3.56   .      .     .     . 142 13.6 4
332  785 2 . 19358 1 . . . 0.0 12.6    . 2.87   .      .     .     . 114 11.8 4
333 1518 2 . 20454 1 . . . 0.0  2.8    . 3.92   .      .     .     .   . 10.6 4
334  466 2 . 20454 1 . . . 0.0  7.1    . 3.51   .      .     .     . 721 11.8 .
335 3527 0 . 20089 1 . . . 0.0  0.6    . 4.15   .      .     .     . 280 10.1 2
336 2635 0 . 23741 1 . . . 0.0  2.1    . 3.34   .      .     .     . 155 10.1 4
337 2286 2 . 20454 1 . . . 0.0  1.8    . 3.64   .      .     .     . 141 10.0 .
338  791 2 . 17167 1 . . . 0.0 16.0    . 3.42   .      .     .     . 475 13.8 2
339 3492 0 . 21915 1 . . . 0.0  0.6    . 4.38   .      .     .     . 269 10.6 2
340 3495 0 . 19358 1 . . . 0.0  5.4    . 4.19   .      .     .     . 141 11.2 2
341  111 2 . 19724 1 . . . 0.0  9.0    . 3.29   .      .     .     . 286 13.1 4
342 3231 0 . 18263 1 . . . 0.0  0.9    . 4.01   .      .     .     . 244 10.5 3
343  625 2 . 17532 1 . . . 0.0 11.1    . 2.84   .      .     .     .   . 12.2 2
344 3157 0 . 13149 1 . . . 0.0  8.9    . 3.76   .      .     .     . 209 10.6 3
345 3021 1 . 17532 1 . . . 0.0  0.5    . 3.76   .      .     .     . 388 10.1 2
346  559 2 . 25568 1 . . . 0.5  0.6    . 3.81   .      .     .     . 160 11.0 4
347 2812 2 . 18628 1 . . . 0.0  3.4    . 3.92   .      .     .     .   .  9.3 2
348 2834 0 . 18993 0 . . . 0.0  0.9    . 3.14   .      .     .     . 191 12.3 2
349 2855 0 . 19724 1 . . . 0.0  1.4    . 3.82   .      .     .     . 249 10.3 2
350  662 2 . 17532 1 . . . 0.0  2.1    . 4.10   .      .     .     . 200  9.0 3
351  727 2 . 24107 1 . . . 0.0 15.0    . 3.40   .      .     .     . 150 11.1 4
352 2716 0 . 19358 1 . . . 0.0  0.6    . 4.19   .      .     .     . 330  9.9 1
353 2698 0 . 22646 1 . . . 0.0  1.3    . 3.40   .      .     .     . 167 10.6 4
354  990 2 . 21550 1 . . . 0.0  1.3    . 3.12   .      .     .     . 125  9.6 2
355 2338 0 . 14245 1 . . . 0.0  1.6    . 3.75   .      .     .     . 145 10.4 3
356 1616 2 . 24472 1 . . . 0.5  2.2    . 3.26   .      .     .     . 171 11.1 4
357 2563 0 . 21185 1 . . . 0.0  3.0    . 3.46   .      .     .     . 109 10.4 4
358 2537 0 . 23376 1 . . . 0.0  0.8    . 3.49   .      .     .     . 314 10.3 3
359 2534 0 . 16802 1 . . . 0.0  0.8    . 2.89   .      .     .     . 419   .  1
360  778 2 . 23376 1 . . . 0.0  1.8    . 3.15   .      .     .     . 183 10.4 4
361  617 1 . 14975 1 . . . 0.0  5.5    . 2.31   .      .     .     . 517 10.4 4
362 2267 1 . 17897 1 . . . 0.0 18.0    . 3.04   .      .     .     . 432  9.7 2
363 2249 0 . 16071 1 . . . 0.0  0.6    . 3.50   .      .     .     . 150  9.9 3
364  359 2 . 21550 1 . . . 0.0  2.7    . 3.35   .      .     .     . 142 11.5 4
365 1925 0 . 23011 1 . . . 0.0  0.9    . 3.58   .      .     .     . 224 10.0 3
366  249 2 . 22280 1 . . . 0.0  1.3    . 3.01   .      .     .     . 223 10.7 3
367 2202 0 . 23376 1 . . . 0.0  1.1    . 3.49   .      .     .     . 166  9.8 3
368   43 2 . 17897 1 . . . 0.0 13.8    . 2.77   .      .     .     . 388   .  4
369 1197 2 . 15341 1 . . . 0.0  4.4    . 4.52   .      .     .     . 102 10.8 4
370 1095 2 . 18263 1 . . . 0.0 16.0    . 3.36   .      .     .     . 384 10.0 3
371  489 2 . 18628 1 . . . 0.5  7.3    . 3.52   .      .     .     . 265 11.1 1
372 2149 0 . 13514 1 . . . 0.0  0.6    . 3.55   .      .     .     . 248 10.3 2
373 2103 0 . 22646 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 3.29   .      .     .     . 190  9.8 2
374 1980 0 . 18628 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 3.10   .      .     .     . 274 10.6 3
375 1347 1 . 18993 1 . . . 0.0  1.7    . 3.24   .      .     .     . 231 10.5 3
376 1478 2 . 16071 0 . . . 0.0  9.5    . 3.63   .      .     .     . 292 10.2 3
377 1987 0 . 12053 1 . . . 0.0  2.2    . 3.76   .      .     .     . 253  9.9 3
378 1168 2 . 21915 1 . . . 0.5  1.8    . 3.62   .      .     .     . 225  9.9 2
379  597 2 . 23011 1 . . . 0.5  3.3    . 2.73   .      .     .     . 224 11.1 4
380 1725 1 . 12053 1 . . . 0.0  2.9    . 4.08   .      .     .     . 418 10.5 3
381 1899 0 . 14975 0 . . . 0.0  1.7    . 3.66   .      .     .     .  92 11.0 4
382  221 2 . 18628 1 . . . 0.0 14.0    . 2.58   .      .     .     . 190 11.6 4
383 1022 1 . 13514 1 . . . 0.5  0.8    . 3.00   .      .     .     .  76 10.8 4
384 1639 0 . 21550 1 . . . 0.0  1.3    . 3.40   .      .     .     . 243  9.7 1
385 1635 0 . 20089 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 2.93   .      .     .     . 209 10.6 3
386 1654 0 . 19724 0 . . . 0.0  1.7    . 2.38   .      .     .     . 166  9.8 3
387 1653 0 . 17897 1 . . . 0.5 13.6    . 3.00   .      .     .     . 233  9.9 3
388 1560 0 . 14610 1 . . . 0.0  0.9    . 3.50   .      .     .     . 117 10.9 4
389 1581 0 . 24472 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 3.06   .      .     .     . 165 10.0 4
390 1419 0 . 24837 0 . . . 0.0  3.0    . 3.15   .      .     .     . 139 10.0 3
391 1443 0 . 14975 1 . . . 0.0  1.2    . 2.80   .      .     .     . 120 11.0 2
392 1368 0 . 25202 1 . . . 0.0  0.4    . 3.03   .      .     .     . 173 10.9 3
393  193 2 . 18993 1 . . . 0.5  0.7    . 2.96   .      .     .     . 319  9.9 4
394 1367 0 . 20819 1 . . . 0.5  2.0    . 3.07   .      .     .     .  80 12.1 4
395 1329 0 . 13149 1 . . . 0.0  1.4    . 3.98   .      .     .     . 402 11.0 1
396 1343 0 . 18263 1 . . . 0.0  1.6    . 3.48   .      .     .     . 277 10.2 2
397 1328 0 . 23376 1 . . . 0.0  0.5    . 3.65   .      .     .     . 425 10.2 4
398 1375 0 . 22646 1 . . . 0.0  7.3    . 3.49   .      .     .     . 189 10.9 4
399 1260 0 . 15341 1 . . . 0.0  8.1    . 2.82   .      .     .     . 193 10.4 2
400 1223 0 . 16071 1 . . . 0.0  0.5    . 3.34   .      .     .     . 258 10.6 2
401  935 2 . 25202 1 . . . 0.0  4.2    . 3.19   .      .     .     . 120 11.1 4
402  943 0 . 18993 1 . . . 0.0  0.8    . 3.01   .      .     .     . 256 10.6 3
403 1141 0 . 24107 1 . . . 0.0  2.5    . 3.33   .      .     .     . 256 10.8 4
404 1092 0 . 14610 1 . . . 0.0  4.6    . 3.60   .      .     .     . 337 10.4 3
405 1150 0 . 18993 1 . . . 0.0  1.0    . 3.64   .      .     .     . 340 10.6 3
406  703 2 . 16802 1 . . . 0.0  4.5    . 2.68   .      .     .     . 219 11.5 4
407 1129 0 . 19724 0 . . . 0.0  1.1    . 3.69   .      .     .     . 220 10.8 3
408 1086 0 . 18628 1 . . . 0.5  1.9    . 3.17   .      .     .     . 162 10.7 3
409 1067 0 . 15706 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 3.73   .      .     .     . 214 10.8 3
410 1072 0 . 14245 1 . . . 0.0  1.5    . 3.81   .      .     .     . 255 10.8 3
411 1119 0 . 18628 1 . . . 0.0  0.6    . 3.57   .      .     .     . 286 10.6 3
412 1097 0 . 24472 1 . . . 0.0  1.0    . 3.58   .      .     .     . 244 10.8 3
413  989 0 . 12784 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 3.23   .      .     .     . 312 10.8 3
414  681 2 . 24472 1 . . . 0.0  1.2    . 2.96   .      .     .     . 174 10.9 3
415 1103 0 . 14245 1 . . . 0.0  0.9    . 3.83   .      .     .     . 180 11.2 4
416 1055 0 . 20819 1 . . . 0.0  1.6    . 3.42   .      .     .     . 143  9.9 3
417  691 0 . 21185 1 . . . 0.0  0.8    . 3.75   .      .     .     . 269 10.4 3
418  976 0 . 19358 1 . . . 0.0  0.7    . 3.29   .      .     .     . 350 10.6 4
```

Here is my R code:

```
#Fitting to the first 312 cases.

#Remove the index column from data frame.
surv.df = surv.df[, 2:20]

#Select only the first 312 rows.
surv.df = surv.df[1:312, ]

#Select the Time and Status data.
Time = surv.df[, 1]
Status = surv.df[, 2]
DeathCode = 2

#Recode the data, 1 for Death and 0 otherwise.
for (i in 1:length(Status)){
  if (Status[i] == DeathCode){
    Status[i] = 1
  }
  else{
    Status[i] = 0
  }}


#Transformed model.
library(survival)
surv.cox5 = coxph(Surv(Time, Status == 1) ~ log(V5) + V10 + log(V11) + log(V13) + log(V19) + V20, data = surv.df, na.action = na.exclude, x = TRUE, y = TRUE)
summary(surv.cox5)
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(Time, Status == 1) ~ log(V5) + V10 + log(V11) + 
    log(V13) + log(V19) + V20, data = surv.df, na.action = na.exclude, 
    x = TRUE, y = TRUE)

  n= 312, number of events= 125 

             coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z Pr(>|z|)    
log(V5)   1.59879   4.94702  0.46644  3.428 0.000609 ***
V10       0.79291   2.20983  0.30021  2.641 0.008260 ** 
log(V11)  0.85272   2.34603  0.10076  8.463  < 2e-16 ***
log(V13) -2.59865   0.07437  0.75502 -3.442 0.000578 ***
log(V19)  2.58709  13.29108  1.11029  2.330 0.019800 *  
V20       0.26482   1.30320  0.13381  1.979 0.047808 *  
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

         exp(coef) exp(-coef) lower .95 upper .95
log(V5)    4.94702    0.20214   1.98294   12.3418
V10        2.20983    0.45252   1.22694    3.9801
log(V11)   2.34603    0.42625   1.92561    2.8582
log(V13)   0.07437   13.44563   0.01693    0.3267
log(V19)  13.29108    0.07524   1.50828  117.1219
V20        1.30320    0.76734   1.00256    1.6940

Concordance= 0.851  (se = 0.018 )
Likelihood ratio test= 203.8  on 6 df,   p=<2e-16
Wald test            = 200  on 6 df,   p=<2e-16
Score (logrank) test = 270.3  on 6 df,   p=<2e-16

#Create a data frame for the predicting data.
attach(surv1.df)

#Predict.
predict(surv.cox5, surv1.df)
          1           2           3           4           5           6 
         NA  1.50016220 -1.06172265  0.27390532          NA -1.79989816 
          7           8           9          10          11          12 
         NA -1.41037651  0.76675246          NA -1.86364166 -1.00384957 
         13          14          15          16          17          18 
 0.61431747 -0.18178635 -0.91578020 -0.44859162 -0.29553557  0.18142133 
         19          20          21          22          23          24 
 1.51731181  2.73561025  0.45343659          NA -1.69174126  0.73747652 
         25          26          27          28          29          30 
         NA  2.16707290 -1.56781633  0.36514351  2.39411007 -1.04386513 
         31          32          33          34          35          36 
 2.05302710  0.57662701 -1.80841761  0.06290383 -0.39864863 -0.20113721 
         37          38          39          40          41          42 
-0.73249850 -0.84314527  2.63646447 -2.09249658  0.33177497 -0.31020506 
         43          44          45          46          47          48 
-0.80104626  1.52933462  0.84350211 -0.43849646          NA  0.80918172 
         49          50          51          52          53          54 
 1.85564227  1.72810572 -1.39277204  1.12503740 -0.50585689  0.38180188 
         55          56          57          58          59          60 
-0.29568127          NA  0.05722203  1.74357667  1.12198156 -1.86903718 
         61          62          63          64          65          66 
-0.84328891 -0.53314129  0.11519848  0.94500973 -0.93102763  0.08394223 
         67          68          69          70          71          72 
 2.23773493 -0.75548703 -0.19638926  2.99658691 -0.13754214 -0.77155299 
         73          74          75          76          77          78 
-0.26585919  0.79870081  2.23758503 -0.68562940  0.05093434  0.97540987 
         79          80          81          82          83          84 
-0.32701092 -0.39553903  0.10250538  1.56880779 -1.58213509 -0.52467266 
         85          86          87          88          89          90 
-0.71618254  1.80746676  1.17630125 -1.51471975  1.78767292 -0.31169046 
         91          92          93          94          95          96 
 1.09176613  0.24600621 -0.61526832  1.74260065 -0.46071045  0.68104996 
         97          98          99         100         101         102 
-1.23833950 -0.79969134 -1.03142416 -0.11849129 -1.19343291  0.55501803 
        103         104         105         106 
-0.88998042 -0.08246400 -0.75757097 -0.36144335
```

I assume the NA values are due to some missing values in the data set.

I am trying to predict survival times, but these values do not appear to make sense. What are these values? Is there another predict function I should be using?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "predict survival times". Survival functions range from 1 to 0 as a function of time. You specify the time and the survival is the outcome.There are quite a few Q&A's on SO on the topic of predicting survival as a function of time. If you are not able to find one that matches your data situation and result, then you should show us what your searching strategies produced and how they  have failed to address the problem.

Comment: The default predictions from coxph function are log-hazard ratios calculated from the combinations of individual data values and regression coefficients. You need to look at an understand the different "types" that the `predict.coxph` function offers. Also read `?summary.coxph`.